# What is the best ORM framework and why?

Tags: orm, frameworks

What is the best ORM Object Relational Mapping framework or architecture in your opinion, And why??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate.

There is a community support behind it. It s widely used. Easy to learn and use.

Comment: So that makes it the best or is that your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is good documented, has support in other frameworks like Spring. Also implements JPA so it's definitly good choice.